# What is the Alternate Universe's Fringe Division logo derived from?

Tags: fringe

[image]

Something seems very familiar about this logo, but for some reason I can't quite pin it down.  Is there a particular organization, real-life historical or fictional, from which this insignia might have been derived?

The particularly familiar-looking bits are large, red-on-black "F"s, back-to-back.  I'm not sure if they're familiar because they're opposing red letters, or because they resemble a pair of red wings outstretched, or perhaps they look like some other shape I've seen somewhere on some government or military organization's banner or insignia.

References from primary canon or official commentary or documentation are preferred, but I also welcome reasonable speculation.  Aside from simple demonstration or explanation of semblance, it would be good if any such speculation also included a logical reason for the similarity.

Comment: @Guiseppe - That really *fixed* the grammar?  I thought it was correct from the start?  Though, opinions do differ regarding dangling prepositions.

Comment: All the answers so far really should have been comments (except probably Thaddeus, who at least mentions how common it is) since they're pretty much all personal opinions.  That said, here's another personal opinion:  [This shot](http://fringepedia.net/w/images/thumb/b/bb/222FringeDivisionAlternate.jpg/100px-222FringeDivisionAlternate.jpg) from [Fringepedia](http://fringepedia.net/wiki/Fringe_Division) reminds me of [Torii gates](http://www.citizenarcane.com/files/2005_Feb_17/inaritorii.jpg) with a piece missing.

Comment: @Iszi This is about four years late, but just to alleviate your mind: opinions don't really differ much regarding dangling prepositions anymore. They are perfectly grammatical, if often less high register than Latin-style ones. You won't find any recent serious style guides or grammar works that consider dangling prepositions to be ungrammatical, only misguided individual people who learnt it from their equally misguided third-grade English teacher. :-)

Answer (score 7):

It made me recall the logo of the game "[Return to Castle Wolfenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_to_Castle_Wolfenstein)".

[image]

Comment: Yeah, something in me keeps screaming it's Nazi-related.  I'm not quite sure if it's this.  Good find.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, it is a very familiar logo image. I can find ten of them without even trying hard. The FF winged shape is distinctive, easy to create, and evocative of angels, winged eagles, and other flying shapes used by the military.

The place which may make it most memorable is [Fallen Footwear's](http://fallenfootwear.com/) logo.

[image: Fallen Footwear Logo]

Comment: Can't recall ever having noticed Fallen Footwear before, but (short of the color scheme) that *is* a good likeness.

Answer (score 1):

It always reminded me of the SS Logo:

[image: SS logo.]

Not to 'F' letters but the circle around and the connotations to a Über police department seem to fit.

Comment: Definitely not what I was thinking of.  However, as I mentioned in response to @Guiseppe, it does feel to me like it might have some relation to Nazis.

Comment: +1 Definitely after being introduced to Fringe Divison with their hard-line tactics and mostly black uniforms, I thought of some kind of SS from the alternate universe. It doesn't map exactly to real-world SS, of course, but there is a slight resemblance. Maybe that's what the writers were going for?

Answer (score 1):

It reminds me, vaguely, of the Norsefire party logo from the V For Vendetta movie.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Slytherincess My answer is essentially the same as the other answers (i.e. unsourced speculation), just without a picture. See for instance, Giuseppe's answer. So unless you want a picture provided (which wasn't specified as a requirement for an answer), I don't really see why my answer is lacking, and I definitely can't see why it would be worth a delete vote.

Comment: Would the second person who voted to delete mind clarifying? I'm really at a loss as to why this is delete-worthy, given that it provides a possible answer to the question asked. If it needs improvement I -am- open to that, but I don't think this is delete-worthy at all.

Comment: @SamuelWalker: The "low-quality post" heuristic decided to throw your answer in the review-queue and it is very easy to say "this is a short answer so it must be crap". Granted, it would be better, if you *had* added pictures. But it isn't nearly worth deleting (*maybe* down-voting).

Answer (score 1):

It actually sort of reminds me of the logo for the game [Fortress Forever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_Forever)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I might be hungry (like Walter always is), but it reminds me of the Jimmy johns sandwich company's logo. With their freakishly fast delivery it might just be a fringe event that needs investigating.

But I think the logo also reminds me of the twin towers which exist in the Walternate dimension but not in ours anymore. The mirrored F's being the mirrored universes and the F's being back to back fighting for a common goal are all nice side effects.